# Relation between a base in a vectorial space and cartesian coordinate system? What is the sense of the Standard Base?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations, coordinate-systems

I'm a little stuck with some concepts and don't find how to unblock.  Possibly it's not a clever question but I need the help of someone to unblock. The problem is related to the concept of "base" and "cartesian coordinates system" in $R^n$.

- First example:

  Suppose the base $B$ = $\{e_1, e_2\}: Gen\{B\} = R^2$. A vector **x** expressed in this base is denoted $[x]_b$. Let the matrix $A=[e_1 \space \space e_2]$. The multiplication  **A** $[x]_b$ return the vector $x$ which is expressed in the standard base. So it means that the base $B$ was defined respect the standard base and also when we talk about calculating the vector $x$ we are referring implicitly to a standard base. Why?
- Second example

  Second:
  Suppose that the base $B$ is not orthogonal (oblique). As we said before, the coordinates of the vectors $[x]_b$ are referred to the **standard base**, so if we calculate the dot product: $<e_1, e_2> \neq 0$. But what would it happen if we calculate this product with the vectors $\{e_1,e_2\}$ expressed from base B (itself). In this case: $e_1 = (1,0)$ and $e_2 = (0,1)$ so $<e_1, e_2> = 0$ and it does not make sense because they are not orthogonal. Where is the mistake? Are *a base* and *cartesian coordinates* the same concept?

I know that these are a little bit and strange questions but I don't know how to unblock myself and any books that I review does not talk about these topics. Apart of these question, I would be grateful if someone recommends me a book of linear algebra that deep in these topics. I look for get more insights about this topic.

A lot of thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with linear functions, there are two concepts which are interchangeable (at least for finite vector spaces). I call this concepts the "world of vectors" and the "world of tuples".

Strictly speaking, vectors and tuples are not the same: Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $K$. Then the elements of $V$ are called vectors, whereas the elements of $K$ are called scalars. The elements of $K^n$ are called $n$-tuples.

Tuples and vectors are related to each other via the concepts of bases and coordinates. As a matter of fact, tuples are often called vectors, which makes it hard for beginners the notice the difference between vectors and tuples.

You cannot really multiply a matrix with a vector: Strictly speaking, you multiply a matrix with a tuple and the result of the operation is also a tuple.

So let's get into details. Let $x$ be a vector (an element of $V$). A priori, $x$ doesn't have coordinates. Coordinates are always relative to a basis. So let $B=(b_1,\ldots,b_n)$ be a basis of $V$. (Please note: For simplicity of notation, I assumed that $V$ has finite dimension.) Then you can write $x$ as $x=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i$ (with $a_i\in K,b_i\in B$). The $a_i$ are called the coordinates of $x$ with respect to $B$.

Now let $K$ be a field, $V,W$ be vector spaces over $K$ with $\dim(V)=n$ and $\dim(W)=m$, $f:V\to W$ be a linear function and $v\in V$. By applying $f$ to $v$, you get $w=f(v)$ with $w\in W$. This is the calculation in the "world of vectors". In the "world of tuples", you additionally need bases to express this relationship: Let $B_V$ be a basis of $V$ and $B_W$ be a basis of $W$. If $[v]_{B_V}$ denotes the $n$-tuple that represents the coordinates of $v$ with respect to $B_V$, $[w]_{B_W}$ denotes the $m$-tuple that represents the coordinates of $w$ with respect to $B_W$, and $A\in K^{m\times n}$ denotes the matrix which represents the linear function $f$ with respect to the bases $B_V$ and $B_W$, you can write $[w]_{B_W} = A [v]_{B_V}$ instead of $w=f(v)$.

$w=f(v)$ is a form of calculating with vectors, whereas $[w]_{B_W} = A [v]_{B_V}$ is a form of calculation with tuples. But linear algebra tells us that both ways of calculating are interchangeable (at least for finite vector spaces).

As for your second example: Speaking in the "world of vectors", $\langle .,.\rangle$ is a bilinear form. Two vectors $x,y$ are called orthogonal iff $\langle x,y\rangle=0$. You can perform this calculation in the "world of tuples", but you have to not only represent $x$ and $y$ by coordinates with respect to some bases, but you must also represent $\langle .,.\rangle$ by its coordinates with respect to the sames bases. And this is where your mistake lies: You neglected the fact that $\langle .,.\rangle$ has to be translated into the "world of tuples" as well.

Comment: Are "a tuple" other way to call "a point"?

Comment: When you consider geometries, you can ask what the elements of the geometry are. Geometries can contain elements that are called points, lines, planes, etc.. The term "point" is mostly used in the context of geometry. The theory of vector spaces however is more general: A vector (and also a tuple) does not necessarily have a geometrical interpretation. Strictly speaking, a $n$-tuple with elements of $K$ is simply a function from $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ to $K$.

Comment: Okay. Lot of thanks !